# C++ how do I read hex bytes from files and store them as pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't mean the file says like "0x0051a" or something, i mean the byte 0x4f is the first byte in the file, and I want to read that and assign it to a pointer.
Here's my code so far. Any advice?

```
unsigned char basePointer;

if (inFile.is_open()) {
    inFile.read(&basePointer, 1); }
```

Comment: Do you mean *read data from files into an array and have `basePointer` (which is not a pointer, btw) point to its beginning*? Because your question currently does not make sense.

Comment: I mean the file startes with a pointer table. I'd like to read the pointers in it into pointers (sorry, forgot to add the * for the question here) and then use those to jump to different offsets in the file

Comment: Are they pointers or offsets? Typically, storing pointers in a file is a bad idea, since next time you load the program, memory may well be in a different place. If they are offsets, use the correct size integer, and apply that as an index to the file-content.

Comment: They're offsets in the file, but I store them as pointers to get to the right offset in the file, right? I haven't figured out that step yet

Comment: No, you want to store them as (typically unsigned) integer values.

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is that you read the value as an unsigned integer [unless the offsets are RELATIVE to something, rather than absolute, and some offsets point "back" from where you are now]

Something like this:

```
uint32_t offset;
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&offset), sizeof(offset));
```

Obviously, without knowing what the exact content of your file is, it's hard to describe what you do with that offset - is it an offset from the start of the file, or from the start of a section within the file? If it's a straight forward offset:

```
inFile.seekg(offset);
inFile.read(...);
```

Again, without knowing what you are going to read from that location, it's really not possible to write code that does exactly what you need, just a rough outline.

Comment: Ok, I got that.  I'm reading some text, making sure it's in the right format and appending each two byte character to a string, which I'll dump to files later.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide a sample of the file? I'm not sure I understand what the file-format is - it sounds like you have a text-file, not a binary file - my solution is for a binary file.